# Scroll to DIV using JQuery not working after page load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, scroll

I am trying to scroll the page to DIV, whose ID is sent through `QueryString`. The HTML content of the page is loaded from the Server side in `SharePoint 2010`.

I have used `setTimeout()` to wait until the content is loaded on the page and after timeout I am applying logic to scroll to div. But The page is not scrolling. Code is as below:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getThankyouMsg, 'sp.js');

function getThankyouMsg() {
    var fid = getQueryStringParameter("fid");
    setTimeout(function () {
        //window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "#" + fid;
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery("#" + fid).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }, 7000);
}

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest what I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find solution for my question. We can use simple JavaScript instead of jQuery `animate` function.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getThankyouMsg, 'sp.js');

function getThankyouMsg() {
    var fid = getQueryStringParameter("fid");
    setTimeout(function () {
        location.hash = "#"+fid; //This line will navigates to Div ID
    }, 7000);
}

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}
```

`Location.Hash = "#divId"` 
will work to scroll down to particular div on the page.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to write your own function to wait for the page to load. There is a jQuery function for that: [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Your scrolling code seems to work fine with dummy code. This might work a bit better for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  getThankyouMsg();
});

function getThankyouMsg() {
  var fid = getQueryStringParameter("fid");
  jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: jQuery("#" + fid).offset().top
  }, 2000);
}

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}
```

That is assuming that getQueryStringParameter returns the correct value. There's no way for me to know this since it depends on your backend and the URL being used.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the reply, But I have to use setTimeout because this code is being used in SharePoint and the data I am retrieving is from SharePoint list, so server side code take time to load, while this JavaScript runs first. So when this script run it did not find DIV.

Comment: It takes 6 to 7 seconds to completely load the page, and after that I have to run this JavaScript function.

Comment: @RahulGokani .ready should prevent code from executing before the dom is ready. Are you adding the div dynamically with javascript or is it hardcoded into the page?

Comment: The DIV is being added on the page from server side (C#) code.